# How to call Android TV soft keyboard for edittext?

Tags: android, input, ime, television, d-pad

I'm developing an android TV app.
I would like to SHOW soft keyboard input while Edittext in focus.

I found the below code for common usage

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(analysisInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

These code are successful to SHOW the soft keyboard, but while i used Dpad (laptop keyboard) Enter button to select the number or character, the soft keyboard will auto HIDE OFF and no input into the Edittext field.

Is it the codes for mobile version which only accepted touch input?

What is the correct code to SHOW the Android TV soft keyboard which able to interact with Dpad?

Comment: Did you find any solutions

Answer (score 3):

For those guys, who have stucked: **laptop keyboard** is not the same as **Dpad**.

Pressing Enter on your **laptop keyboard** you will always get `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`.

For testing your **Dpad** input you have to enable it on your emulator.

Here are some steps:

[image][image][image]

Now you can test all dpad actions.

[image]